# How to pop up an app when user taps a field in my app

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a variant of the typical "Tip Calculator" app. I want the user to be able to tap a field in my app and have a simple calculator pop up so that they can add their items from the receipt (the output to which is input to my app). My app will then calculate the tax due, add the tip amount, calculate the total amount due, and allow splitting the bill among the guests (all of this part is done).

I've searched Google and stack overflow and cannot find any help. I've also searched the App Store for any similar apps but found none. I'm a newbie so maybe my search queries aren't quite right. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you try to popup a calculator app? Just display a simply calculator as part of your own app.

Comment: I thought popping up an existing Calculator app would be easier to do. I don't know how to display a calculator as part of my own app.

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a calculator app if you don't have a calculator in it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. None of the tip "calculators" in the App Store have a calculator in them. All they do is take an overall meal cost and calculate a tip. I want the user to be able to use a calculator to determine the overall meal cost (based on adding item costs from the receipt). They could I suppose just use the Calculator app that comes with the iPhone. (I hope I'm making sense.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to make a UIWindow with your calculator or whatever then when it's ready, use one of the UIView class methods to add it to the main screen view. There are several built-in special effects or if you know 3D programming and such you can make your own.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll have to read up on UIWindows and UIView classes. I don't know anything about 3D programming. Maybe the best solution is to have the user tally up their meal cost using the existing Calculator app. I could then use that as input to my app. Thanks again.